# Find path to binary without which

Tags: linux, bash, shell

An Open Source project I contribute to has a dependency on `which` that I'd like to remove, as some Linux distros (like the cloud version of Fedora 20) don't ship with it by default, and I believe it's ugly to force its install, given how trivial our use of it is.

All we're doing is finding the path to the Java binary, then using that info to set `$JAVA_HOME`.

Is there a way to do that with Bash built-ins? In general, how can I somewhat-elegantly find a binary while minimizing dependencies (like `which`)? Or is it a better call to just use `which`, for example if the only alternative is to run `find` against directories in `$PATH` and the community believes that to be exceedingly inelegant?

Note that it's extremely ineffective to Google for `which`-related things.

Comment: It's very much better not to use `which`, as `which` is an external program using (slightly) different logic than the shell does itself, and thus can potentially give you a potentially inaccurate result! `type` uses the shell's built-in resolution, and is guaranteed to behave the same way the shell really will in practice.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the bug-avoidance tip. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The POSIX-ly correct way:

```
cmd=$(command -v whatever)
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe by parsing the output of the shell builtin `type` ?

```
~/ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
~/ type type
type is a shell builtin
```

Tested with `zsh`, `bash` and `sh`

If you are using `bash`, the option `-P` gives you directly the result you want:

```
~/ type -P python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I did not mean "the program type", but the command `type <program>`

Comment: ...as using `type -P` will return an exact result in a manner that needs no parsing.

Comment: Sure, but the question specifies bash specifically.

Comment: You are wright, and that's why I added this example! I just did not know it as I'm usually using zsh instead of bash...

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. The script in question's shebang is for bash, so this is bash-specific.

Comment: In `zsh`, you would use the POSIX-compatible `command -v` instead.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is already mentioned "type". But there is an additional command for this task:

```
 whereis -b <file>
```

locates binary for specified files